# Is it possible to get the street details based on a geo location in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to get the nearby street details based on a geo-location?
Like suppose my geo-location is (x,y) co-ordinates. using this is it possible to get the list
of streets, co-ordinates which form the street and any other data related to street around that geo-location?
All of this using Google map apis.

Although, there are apis provided by:
http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyStreetsOSMJSON?lat=37.451&lng=-122.18&username=demo

I want this exact functionality as shown in the link above using google apis. Is it possible?

Comment: have you checked https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search?

Comment: Your link gives an error message (limit exceeded).

Comment: Link works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

No - vector data extraction such as you describe is not supported by the Google Maps API.